# how to get response of json data in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am posting my data in url with this block of code.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"company_name=%@&email_id=%@&password=%@",_CompanyName.text,_Email.text, _Password.text];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[urlString length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
NSString *url = @"http://dev1.brainpulse.org/quickmanhelp/webservice/api.php?act=registration";
[req setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req setHTTPBody:[urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:
    ^(NSURLResponse *reponse , NSData *data, NSError *error){
         NSError *errre1;
         dictLogin=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&errre1];
         NSLog(@"result is%@ :",dictLogin);
         NSLog(@"result is%@ :",urlString);
         [user setObject:[dictLogin objectForKey:@"company_name"] forKey:@"company_name"];
         [user setObject:[dictLogin objectForKey:@"email_id"] forKey:@"email_id"];
         [user setObject:[dictLogin objectForKey:@"passord"] forKey:@"password"];
```

Now i don't know ho to get response when i am going to login screen,

JSON

```
result : "Successful"
data
0
user_id : "1"
email_id : "gupta.monu4@gmail.com"
password : "monu"
phone_no : ""
user_type : "admin"
company_name : "Brainpulse"
```

This is my json structure.

Comment: this is your response part NSLog(@"result is%@ :",dictLogin);,, can you show your result

Comment: This is my result:-  2015-11-07 15:46:02.619 Quick man help[1081:102593] result is{
    data =     (
                {
            "company_name" = Brainpulse;
            "email_id" = "gupta.monu4@gmail.com";
            password = monu;
            "phone_no" = "";
            "user_id" = 1;
            "user_type" = admin;
        }
    );
    result = Successful;

Comment: check the answer bro

Comment: Your POST request is not properly setup with a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. You will get an error from the server. If your server accepts JSON as content type, I would recommend to use `application/json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check like this is avoid the crash and memory leaks

```
  // create the one global array for save
  NSMutableArray *user =[NSMutableArray new];

dictLogin=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&errre1];

if (dictLogin)
{
// serilize your data
    if ([[dictLogin objectForKey:@"result"] isEqualToString:"Successful"])
    {

        [user removeAllobjects];
       // assign into one array
        NSArray *TempArray = dictLogin[@"data"];

        for (NSDictionary *tmp in TempArray)
         {
          // careate one temporary dictionary
           NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];


      // store your data to Dictionary or array
        [tmpDict setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"company_name"] forKey:@"company_name"];
         [tmpDict setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"email_id"] forKey:@"email_id"];

        if ([tmp objectForKey:@"passord"] != nil) {
         [tmpDict setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"passord"] forKey:@"password"];
 }


            [user addobject:tmpDict];

            // then use your data where u need

     }
     else
     {
       // show the failure report
      }
}
else
{
 // show the failure report
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir i am trying to implement this code and back to you.

Comment: ya sure if you need a support I surely help with you

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: password)'

Comment: i am getting this error and app crash on login button click.

Comment: @sandeeptomar -- on your response key **password** contains nil object , thats is the error, so check the updated answer and check each key if you need

Comment: @sandeeptomar -- r u checked the updated answer , will u need any suport

Comment: @sandeeptomar --- Tanx bro for your response, always follow this way, this is avoid your crash on webservice call, ok if my answer is useful give the upvote

Comment: Thanks for your advise bro

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSUserdefauls' declares the selector 'addObjects.' please give me some suggestions.

Comment: because there is no instance method for addObjects in userdefaults, put the break point and check once

Comment: Hello sir hope you doing fine, i am perfectly get the output in debugger area from the code you provided for me, but i want to add if condition in it. for example if email id and password exist then move to next page on login button. Please help me for this concern.

Comment: simple bro, this is my no 9790811202 call me when u r free

Comment: hello sir i was call you a minute ago.

Comment: Hello sir are you there?;. i need your help sir.

Comment: Thanks your response sir, i just working on uitabbarcontroller from last three days, In simple i want a structure like " when we open App Store in device at the bottom there is uitabbaritem and upper there is a uisegmentcontroller " how to change view inside uitabbaritem on the click of segment controller.

Comment: Please give me some idea so i can move on this structure.